# jQuery: on checked checkbox append form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi Everyone I use a check box to load form if checked I want load form else remove form the bellow is my code

```
 $('.checkbox-primary').change(function () {
        $url = $('.form-edit').attr('action');
        $form = $('.form-edit').serialize();
        $.post($url, $form ,function ($data) {

            var x=document.getElementById("filebox_edit_hardcopylocation_warehouse");
            var warehouse=document.getElementById("filebox_edit_hardcopylocation_warehouse");
            if(x){
                $('.panel-footer').removeChild(warehouse);
                alert("yes");
            }
            else
            {
                $('.form-edit').append('<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">WareHouse: </label> <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"> <select id="filebox_edit_hardcopylocation_warehouse" name="filebox_edit[hardcopylocation][warehouse]" class="form-control"><option value="">Please Select Warehouse</option><option value="6">HQ4</option><option value="7">KTC</option></select> </div> </div> <select id="filebox_edit_hardcopylocation_floor" name="filebox_edit[hardcopylocation][floor]" class="form-control"><option value="">Please Select Floor</option><option value="1">first floor</option><option value="2">second floor</option><option value="3">second floor</option><option value="4">first floor</option></select><select id="filebox_edit_hardcopylocation_room" name="filebox_edit[hardcopylocation][room]" class="form-control"><option value="">Please Select Room</option><option value="9">R122</option><option value="10">R2</option></select><select id="filebox_edit_hardcopylocation_rack" name="filebox_edit[hardcopylocation][rack]" class="form-control"><option value="">Please Select Rack</option><option value="15">RA3456</option><option value="16">RA1</option><option value="17">RA2</option><option value="18">RA39</option></select>')

            }

        })
    });
```

Comment: before the -1 rain, what seems to be the problem :) any errors etc. also dont mix vanilla js API and jquery is ugly a.f. and it is error prone

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I want to remove form when I checked the check box

Comment: Adding some HTML would be useful. Now we have to guess what each ID/class is for.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can check:

```
$('.checkbox-primary').change(function () {
    $(this).is(":checked") {
          // checkbox is checked
    } else {
          // It is unchecked
    }
}
```